# Programmatically change http settings in IE 11 with javascript

Tags: javascript, windows, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an issue related to this IE11 bug using SPDY http protocol on Windows 8.

http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/813993/ie11-sites-that-support-spdy-do-not-load-first-time-when-ie-is-configured-to-use-a-proxy-server-and-spdy-is-enabled

I cannot ask our users to all go to Internet Options and disable the 'Use SPDY/3' checkbox, so I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this using Javascript. (Angular app). I am wondering if the Angular $httpProvider might help, but I am unable to find any docs on it.

Help ??
Thanks

Comment: JavaScript can not change browser settings.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do that; and changing the user's browser settings globally would be the wrong way to go about this anyway. The right thing to do would be to get a network capture of the failure and get it on the CONNECT bug so MSFT can fix it. You could also optionally configure your server not to use SPDY with IE clients, assuming this is legitimately a bug in IE.